# Is OpenGL multithreaded?

Tags: multithreading, opengl, thread-safety

There are libraries that underhood work using multiple threads. Also there are libraries that are thread safe - objects support usage running in multiple threads.

What about OpenGL? Is it multithreaded? Is it thread safe?

Comment: A quick Google search suggests that on Mac OS X it [is](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_threading/opengl_threading.html). [This](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_and_multithreading) also says it is multithreaded in windows, but the user has to manually "lock" and "unlock".

Comment: @meowgoesthedog does this link say the lib uses multiple threads on OS X? Or does it say how to handle the situation if you want to use it in a multithreaded application?

Comment: It says that if you use multiple contexts the driver will be busy synchronizing them (instead of doing useful work); this suggests that no explicit synchronization will need to be done on the user end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If depends on what you mean by "multithreaded".

If you are thinking about C++ feature like (sharing memory, using locks, etc), then no, OpenGL does not work that way. But this doesn't mean than you can not use threads. You can, with special care.

The main thing to be aware of is the context. You can have several contexts. You can set as current any context for any thread, but only one can be set as current for a thread, not two contexts for the same thread.

Using *shared contexts* gives you a bit of advantage with multithreading. They share some resources like textures and VBOs. For example, you set *ctx1* as current for a thread and use gl-commands in that thread to update a texture to the GPU. Once the update is finished that texture is available for the shared context *ctx2* set as current in other thread. The OGL wiki tells about this [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_and_multithreading) and [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Object#Object_Sharing).

Being that said, the question is "why do I need mutlthreading?" The common answer is "to make things happen faster". The point is that the GPU will draw step by step (using all of its parallelism, of course) but will NOT process two draw commands at the same time. Also, setting a context as current has a light perfomance penalty.

What you likely are looking for is *sending data to GPU while it's rendering*. You can use shared contexts as I wrote before. But there are other technics like [streaming](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming), you can read more at [OpenGL Insights book](http://openglinsights.com/) Chapter 28 "Asynchronous Buffer Transfers".